# Split date ranges into corresponding weeks

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have date ranges called from and to.I want to convert it to weeks.
Suppose from date is 1-10-2014 and to date is 31-10-2014

Then result is:

1st week : 01-10-2014 to 04-10-2014
2nd : 05-102014 to 11-10-2014
3rd : 12-10-2014 to 18-10-2014
4th : 19-10-2014 to 25-10-2014
5th : 26-10-2014 to 31-10-2014

In php.I try several code but that didn't given the absolute result only give 01 to 7 , 8 to 14 etc.
Pls help.

I already try answers from

```
Get the date of one week from today with PHP in stack overflow


date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This snippet uses Sunday as the first day of the week:

```
    $start = new DateTime('2014-10-01');
    $end = new DateTime('2014-10-31 23:59');
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $weekNumber = 1;
    $weeks = array();
    foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
        $weeks[$weekNumber][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($date->format('w') == 6) {
            $weekNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Each week will have all the days in it.

If you just want the first and last days of each week then you can just use `array_shift` and `array_pop` to get them.  For example, for the first week you can use:

```
    $wk1Start = array_shift($weeks[1]); //gives you first day of week 1
    $wk1End = array_pop($weeks[1]); // give you the last day of week 1
```

If you want the start and end dates for each week, here is a way of doing it:

```
    $ranges = array_map(function($week) {
        return 'start: ' . array_shift($week) 
            . ', end: ' . array_pop($week); },
    $weeks);
```

This is the output of `$ranges` for me:

```
    Array
    (
        [1] => start: 2014-10-01, end: 2014-10-04
        [2] => start: 2014-10-05, end: 2014-10-11
        [3] => start: 2014-10-12, end: 2014-10-18
        [4] => start: 2014-10-19, end: 2014-10-25
        [5] => start: 2014-10-26, end: 2014-10-31
    )
```

Comment: what is the case that fails?

Comment: when i print $weeks got                                                 Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 2014-10-01 [1] => 2014-10-02 [2] => 2014-10-03 [3] => 2014-10-04 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2014-10-05 [1] => 2014-10-06 [2] => 2014-10-07 [3] => 2014-10-08 [4] => 2014-10-09 [5] => 2014-10-10 [6] => 2014-10-11 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2014-10-12 [1] => 2014-10-13 [2] => 2014-10-14 [3] => 2014-10-15 [4] => 2014-10-16 [5] => 2014-10-17 [6] => 2014-10-18 ) etc

Comment: That is as expected, it will show you all the days in the week.  If you just want the start and end dates, shift and pop each array.

Comment: If you look at each array in `$weeks`, the first element and the last element are the date ranges you specified.  $start = `array_shift($weeks[1])` will give you the first day of the first week and `array_pop($weeks[1])` will give you the last day of the first week.  Similarly for the other weeks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65556/discussion-between-adarsh-m-pallickal-and-ymas).

Comment: @ymas can you pls, tell me how can I get week number of the year instead of 1, 2, 3

Comment: @NadeemGorsi you can start the counter from $date->format("W"), where date is the first day in your range, is this what you mean?

Comment: yes @ymas I did that even we don't need a counter using just like this `$weeks["week_".$date->format('W')][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');` . Thanks for replay. Happy Coding!

Comment: Hello @NadeemGorsi bear in mind the first day of the week if you're going to do it like that.  Good job!

Comment: yes I noticed the first day of the year is first day of week. Thankx @ymas

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the week starting day (set to Monday at the moment):

```
$fromDate = '2018-05-03';
$toDate = '2018-08-11';
$result = getWeekRanges($fromDate, $toDate);
array_walk_recursive($result, 'applyFormat');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

function getWeekRanges($start, $end) {
    $timeStart = strtotime($start);
    $timeEnd   = strtotime($end);
    $out       = [];
    $milestones[] = $timeStart;
    $timeEndWeek = strtotime('next Monday', $timeStart);
    while ($timeEndWeek < $timeEnd) {
        $milestones[] = $timeEndWeek;
        $timeEndWeek = strtotime('+1 week', $timeEndWeek);
    }
    $milestones[] = $timeEnd;
    $count = count($milestones);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if( $i == $count - 1) {
            $out[] = [
                'start' => $milestones[$i - 1],
                'end'   => $milestones[$i]
            ];
        }else{
            $out[] = [
                'start' => $milestones[$i - 1],
                'end'   => $milestones[$i] - 1
            ];
        }
    }
    return $out;
}


function applyFormat(&$item) {
    $item = date('Y-m-d', $item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-10-01'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-10-31'));
$i=1;
for($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'))) {
    echo getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date, $i);
    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}

function getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date, $i) {
    $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
    $year =  date('Y', strtotime($date));
    $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+1")); //Returns the date of monday in week
    if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;
    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-7"));   //Returns the date of sunday in week
    if($to > $end_date) $to = $end_date;
    echo "$i th ".$from." to ".$to.'<br>';
}
```

output :-

```
1 th 2014-10-01 to 2014-10-05
2 th 2014-10-06 to 2014-10-12
3 th 2014-10-13 to 2014-10-19
4 th 2014-10-20 to 2014-10-26
5 th 2014-10-27 to 2014-10-31
```

Comment: there is some dates missing.05,12,19,26. I want the sundays also

Comment: check now updated for error you need to pass correct format in start and end date

Comment: needed output :1 th 2014-10-01 to 2014-10-04
2 th 2014-10-05 to 2014-10-11
3 th 2014-10-12 to 2014-10-18
4 th 2014-10-19 to 2014-10-25
5 th 2014-10-26 to 2014-10-31

Comment: when i select dec 1st to 31st output is 1 th 2014-12-01 to 2014-12-07
2 th 2014-12-08 to 2014-12-14
3 th 2014-12-15 to 2014-12-21
4 th 2014-12-22 to 2014-12-28
5 th 2014-12-01 to 2014-01-05 there is some missing dates 29,30,31

Comment: have you passing correct format to start and end date ? echo your start and end date and check

Comment: can you check with december 2014?that show an error

Comment: i think last week goes to next year so need also year change in calculation